# How to best transfer a document to a SAPUI5 framwork?

Tags: html, xml, document, sapui5

I'd like to achieve the following and I'm looking for ideas. I have a document and I want to represent/transform this content in/to a nice SAPUI5 framework. My idea is the following: a split app with having the paragraph titles in the master view (plus a search function on top) and the respective content in the detail view.

I'd like to know from you if

a) you might want to share your ideas and hints on alternatives.

b) this can be achieved within one single file (i.e. all the code for the split app and document content in one html) and maybe using pure html code (xml also feasible) - against the background of easily handing a large amount of text available in html.

c) if you happen to have/know a reusable template.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question. I went through a similar exercise once, [re-presenting my site with UI5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZUXz5f1CHI).

To your questions:

(a) I would think that the approach you suggest is a good one

(b) You can indeed include all the app in a single file, I do that often by using script templates, even with XML Views. You can see some examples in my [sapui5bin repository](https://github.com/qmacro/sapui5bin), in particular in the [SinglePageExamples folder](https://github.com/qmacro/sapui5bin/tree/master/SinglePageExamples). Have a look at this html file for example: https://github.com/qmacro/sapui5bin/blob/master/SinglePageExamples/SAP-Inside-Track-Sheffield-2014/end.html

What I would suggest is, rather than intermingle the document content and the app & view definitions, maintain the content of your document separately, for example, in XML or JSON, and use a client side model to load it in and bind the parts to the right places.

Comment: Hi DJ, 
that is / you are world-class!
Well, then I'm basically ready to start, however, one big problem still persists. I have plenty of configuration guides in word doc(x) format that want to be transfered to SAPUI5. 
The docs are mainly process descriptions, i.e. there's mostly numbered lists. The idea (only option apart from copy&pasting?) is to convert word doc to html.
Then including the html in xml views à la:  <html:tr>
    <html:td>xxxx</html:td>
    <html:td>xxxx</html:td>
     </html:tr>

Comment: I've been searching through google "for ages" without any decent result. Ok, these two are quite nice:
1) coypy&paste content to Google docs -> save as html; result is quite ok
2) using Dreamweaver after saving doc as html plus this tut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWKjE77oUFM

However, as I said, it's a lot about numbered lists. I simply cannot find a decent solution that would convert word doc lists into proper <ul><li></li></ul> code (the above solutions cannot deal with that - but it's absolutely vital). Is there a solution for this  <ul> conversion thing?

Comment: example output for a list conversion: <p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst style='text-indent:-18.0pt'>1.<span
style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>Hallo</p>  -> No chance to get a clean <ul><li> output